# "Unresolved external" errors while compiling C++Builder 6 project

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have some errors while compiling a C++Builder 6 threads project. I don't know how to fix them.

Unit1.cpp:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"

using namespace std;

int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
T1 *Thread1, *Thread2;
bool Term1, Term2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}

void __fastcall T1::Execute()
{
    do
        Synchronize (UpdateTimer);
    while (!Terminated);
}
//-----------------------------------------------
void __fastcall T1::UpdateTimer()
{
    Timer->Enabled = !Terminated;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    ComboBox1->ItemIndex = 3;
    ComboBox2->ItemIndex = 3;
    Thread1 = new T1(false);
    Thread1->Timer = Timer1;
    Thread1->FreeOnTerminate = true;
    Term1 = false;
    Thread2 = new T1(true);
    Thread2->Timer = Timer2;
    Thread2->FreeOnTerminate = true;
    Term2 = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
    i1++;
    Label1->Caption = i1;
    Timer1->Enabled = false;

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer2Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
    i2++;
    Label2->Caption = i2;
    Timer2->Enabled = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BRes1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (!Term1)
        Thread1->Resume();
    else ShowMessage("Ïîòîê óæå çàâåðøåí");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BRes2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (!Term2)
        Thread2->Resume();
    else ShowMessage("Ïîòîê óæå çàâåðøåí");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BTerm1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Thread1->Terminate();
    Term1 = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BTerm2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Thread2->Terminate();
    Term2 = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BSuspend1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (!Term1)
        Thread1->Suspend();
    else ShowMessage("Ïîòîê óæå çàâåðøåí");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BSuspend2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (!Term2)
        Thread2->Suspend();
    else ShowMessage("Ïîòîê óæå çàâåðøåí");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BSyncClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (Term1 || Term2)
        ShowMessage("Ïîòîê óæå çàâåðøåí");
    else
    {
        if (!Thread1->Suspended)
            Thread1->Suspend();
        if (!Thread2->Suspended)
            Thread2->Suspend();
        Timer1->Enabled = false;
        Timer2->Enabled = false;
        i1 = 0;
        i2 = 0;
        Thread1->Resume();
        Thread2->Resume();
    }

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::ComboBox1Change(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (Term1)
        ShowMessage("Ïîòîê óæå çàâåðøåí");
    else
        switch (ComboBox1->ItemIndex)
        {
            case 0: Thread1->Priority = tpIdle;          break;
            case 1: Thread1->Priority = tpLowest;        break;
            case 2: Thread1->Priority = tpLower;         break;
            case 3: Thread1->Priority = tpNormal;        break;
            case 4: Thread1->Priority = tpHigher;        break;
            case 5: Thread1->Priority = tpHighest;       break;
            case 6: Thread1->Priority = tpTimeCritical;  break;
        }

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::ComboBox2Change(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (Term2)
        ShowMessage("Ïîòîê óæå çàâåðøåí");
    else
        switch (ComboBox2->ItemIndex)
        {
            case 0: Thread2->Priority = tpIdle;          break;
            case 1: Thread2->Priority = tpLowest;        break;
            case 2: Thread2->Priority = tpLower;         break;
            case 3: Thread2->Priority = tpNormal;        break;
            case 4: Thread2->Priority = tpHigher;        break;
            case 5: Thread2->Priority = tpHighest;       break;
            case 6: Thread2->Priority = tpTimeCritical;  break;
        }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Uni1.h

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
#include <ExtCtrls.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TGroupBox *GroupBox1;
    TGroupBox *GroupBox2;
    TLabel *Label1;
    TButton *BRes1;
    TButton *BSuspend1;
    TButton *BTerm1;
    TLabel *Label2;
    TButton *BRes2;
    TButton *BSuspend2;
    TButton *BTerm2;
    TComboBox *ComboBox1;
    TComboBox *ComboBox2;
    TButton *BSync;
    TTimer *Timer1;
    TTimer *Timer2;
    void __fastcall FormCreate(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Timer2Timer(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall BRes1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall BRes2Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall BTerm1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall BTerm2Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall BSuspend1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall BSuspend2Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall BSyncClick(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall ComboBox1Change(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall ComboBox2Change(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};

class T1 : public TThread
{
private:
    void _fastcall UpdateTimer();
protected:
    void _fastcall Execute();
public:
    __fastcall T1(bool CreateSuspended);
    TTimer *Timer;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

**Errors:**

```
[Linker Error] Unresolved external 't1::' referenced from C:\USERS\ALEXEY\DESKTOP\CCC\UNIT1.OBJ
[Linker Error] Unresolved external '__fastcall T1::T1(bool)' referenced from C:\USERS\ALEXEY\DESKTOP\CCC\UNIT1.OBJ
```

Comment: Unresolved external `t1::` is the linker's way of telling you that C++ is case-sensitive. Somewhere in your code you typed `t1` instead of `T1`.

Comment: Unresolved external '__fastcall T1::T1(bool)' means that you declared a constructor but didn't care to implement it...

Comment: @Lundin but how can i fix this?

Comment: I'm really not sure how I could be any clearer. Do a text search for `t1` in your project, any hits? The implement the constructor you wrote instead of just providing a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a class `T1` that has a constructor declared in it, but you did not actually implement that constructor.  That is what the linker is complaining about.

You need to add that implementation to your `.cpp` file, eg:

```cpp
__fastcall T1::T1(bool CreateSuspended)
    : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{
    FreeOnTerminate = true; // <-- this should be moved in here
}
```

That will solve the linker error.

---

That being said, you have some design flaws in your code.

You are creating the `Thread1` object with `CreateSuspended=false`, which gives it permission to start running *immediately* once its constructor is finished.  But you are not assigning its `Timer` member until after the constructor has exited.  So the thread can start running before its `Timer` is assigned.  The only reason this "works" in your example is because your use of `TThread::Synchronize()` will not call `T1::UpdateTimer()` until after `TForm1::FormCreate()` <sup>1</sup> has assigned the `Timer` member and exited

<sup>1: BTW, you should NOT be using that event in C++ at all, as it can cause *undefined behavior*. Use the Form's constructor instead.</sup>

But this is not a good design to rely on.  Since your thread class depends on an external `TTimer` object, you should either:

- create the `Thread1` object with `CreateSuspended=true` instead, and then `Resume()` that thread after you have fully initialized its members.  Which is what you are doing with the `Thread2` object.
- pass the desired `TTimer` object pointer to each thread's constructor, eg:

```cpp
class T1 : public TThread
{
private:
    TTimer *Timer;
    void _fastcall UpdateTimer();
protected:
    void _fastcall Execute();
public:
    __fastcall T1(bool CreateSuspended, TTimer *ATimer);
};

...

__fastcall T1::T1(bool CreateSuspended, TTimer *ATimer)
    : TThread(CreateSuspended), Timer(ATimer)
{
    FreeOnTerminate = true;
}

...

Thread1 = new T1(false, Timer1);
Thread2 = new T1(true, Timer2);
```

Also, you are setting `FreeOnTerminate=true` for both threads, but you are not assigning an `OnTerminate` event handler to each thread, so you have no way to know for sure if the threads are actually valid when you try to access them in your button `OnClick` event handlers.  If the threads terminate for any reason, including an unexpected crash, then you will be accessing dangling pointers.

Also, you should not be `Suspend()`'ing a running thread from outside of that thread's own `Execute()` method for ANY reason.  You don't know the state of the thread at the time of the suspension.  It could be (and likely will be, in this case) in the middle of a `Synchronize()` call, which can cause deadlocks that are waiting on the suspended `Synchronize()` to finish its work.  If you want to pause a worker thread, use a separate flag instead, or even a `TEvent`, which the thread can check periodically when it is safe and appropriate to do so.

---

Lastly, calling `TThread::Synchronize()` in a tight loop in a worker thread, as you are doing, is a *complete waste* of a worker thread, since *ALL* of its work is being performed in the main UI thread only.  You may as well just get rid of your `TThread` class completely. Using a `TTimer` instead will suffice, or a `PostMessage()` loop, or a `TApplication::OnIdle` event handler, or a `TAction(Manager)::OnUpdate` event handler, etc. Many different ways to approach this.